# rxjava nested using operators dispose order incorrect

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm having trouble with understanding cancel behaviour in RX, when using the `using` operator.

The scenario is like this: I have to run a jdbc query and be able to cancel it from another thread. I'm trying to replicate the behaviour in the following standalone program.

First, I'm creating a `Connection` Object with the `using` operator, and inside it I'm using `using` again, with a `Statement` object. The inner-most logic is just simulating a long running query, with a `Flowable.interval`.

I run this

```java
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
@Slf4j
public class TestRX {

  static class Connection implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
      log.info("Closing Connection");
    }
  }
  static class Statement implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
      log.info("Closing Statement");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Flowable<Long> f = Flowable.using(
      Connection::new,
      a -> Flowable.using(
        Statement::new,
        b -> Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.from(e)).takeWhile(l->l<6),
        Statement::close
      ),
      Connection::close
    );
    Future<Long> future = f.lastOrError().toFuture();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    future.cancel(true);
    e.shutdown();
  }
}
```

A flowable is constructed, converted to `Future` object, then `cancel` is called on that. Surprisingly, the close of the resource objects happens in reverse order. This is the output I get:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52171', transport: 'socket'
17:24:20.880 [main] INFO com.TestRX - Closing Connection
17:24:20.884 [main] INFO com.TestRX - Closing Statement
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52171', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Whereas if there's no cancel and I let it run normally, the close order is okay:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52213', transport: 'socket'
17:26:45.311 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.TestRX - Closing Statement
17:26:45.315 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.TestRX - Closing Connection
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52213', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is that happening? Am I doing something wrong? How should cancel be implemented?

It seems unrelated to the Future-conversion, as the following code also closes the resources in wrong order (first close connection the close statement).

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Flowable<Long> f = Flowable.using(
      Connection::new,
      a -> Flowable.using(
        Statement::new,
        b -> Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.from(e)).takeWhile(l->l<6),
        Statement::close
      ),
      Connection::close
    );
    Disposable d = f.subscribe();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    d.dispose();
    e.shutdown();
  }
```

Comment: See http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#using-java.util.concurrent.Callable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-boolean-

Comment: @akarnokd do you mean to say it's the expected behaviour? In that case, how should the client code be organized so that disposal happens in the correct order?

Comment: It can't be done unless you flatten the resource into one `using` or externalize the dispose process which requires a lot of atomics juggling.

Comment: @akarnokd My issue is this: `using` is supposed to create a disposable resource. When I nest two `using` blocks, the inner resource can be dependent on the outer resource. So the cleanup should happen inside-out, just like it happens in success/failure scenarios. Why is cancel any different? Why is cancel doing the cleanup outside-in?

Comment: It is a limitation of the 2.x `using` and has been updated with [3.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6534).

Comment: Thanks. I did a lot of googling but no combination of keywords took me to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6534. Anyway, since 3.x is only months away, I'm fine waiting for that. I think my usage is not using any functionality that could break with the upgrade.

Comment: Meanwhile, in my case, it's mostly okay if the outer resource is cleaned first. If the inner resource is dependent, closing the outer resource anyway renders the inner resource unusable. Only thing is, the code would fail from inside-out. The outside code just needs to be aware that this is a cancellation, not a failure.